# "invalid value encountered in double_scalars" error

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I wrote a while loop in python with the following line inside it:

```
A=[i/j for i,j in zip(B,C) if j>0]
```

where **B**, **C** are lists. But I get the "invalid value encountered in double_scalars" error with the message:

```
[inf nan  1.]
G:\example.py:66: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  A=[i/j for i,j in zip(B,C) if j>0]
```

I searched for the error and realized that this is mainly because of a division by zero. But as it is obvious, I removed the zero from denominator.

I appreciate every advice to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you give a us a reproducible problem, for instance a `B` and `C` list that would raise this error?

Comment: Division by zero would raise an `ZeroDivisionError`. So the cause of your error is likely something else.

Comment: run `numpy.seterr('raise')` and run your code. This will show you where is your problem. Most chances your are dividing by very small number which cause a floating point accuracy problems.